# How to start progress bar from middle in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I have progress bar inderterminate, how I start it from middle, when push left button to move left, when push right button to move right, this work now but the bar must start in centre, my bar start left now.

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the value attibute and set it to half the maximum. (By default, the maximum is 100)

```
Progressbar(root, mode="indeterminate", value="50")
```

Here's the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Progressbar)

Comment: Yes,it work,but have a problem,when push the button + ,the progress bar mоves one step back and then i can moves forward.